# How to update by Ignoring null values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have my data like this,

### Heading

[image: Name Gender Salary(L) Sam null null null M null null null 3.45 Priya null null null F null null null 4.02]

& I want output in

Name Gender Salary
Sam   M     3.45
Priya F     4.02

[image]

Please help me out.
thank you.

Comment: @Alexander If I do Name is not null then Gender,Salary(L) columns will be ignored.

Comment: your data is badly screwed up.  Can you fix the null name rows?

Comment: How do you define that the row Salary=3.45 matches Name=Sam and not Name=Priya? I do not see any reason for this conclusion.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d527f565e6541db2ffb8c805b09d00f0

Comment: You need to rethink something - the table definition on the link suggest you would have 1 row per name but the data you have inserted indicates that you wish to store as key value pairs in which case the table design is wrong.

Comment: You have not answered my question...

Comment: It seems, the sample of data is incorrect. The fields are not related each other and it's not possible to consider a row in the table as an entity.

Answer (score 1):

```
This is not a practical scenario. At least you must have a Order by column or a sequence number to manage your data set.  but try something like this. Most probably, **Order by** cause you many issues wile you working with the real data set.


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_names
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NAME) rowid, NAME FROM Heading 
WHERE NAME IS NOT NULL;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_gender
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NAME) rowid, gender FROM Heading 
WHERE gender IS NOT NULL;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_salary
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NAME) rowid, salary FROM Heading 
WHERE salary IS NOT NULL;

SELECT nm.name, tg.gender, sl.salary FROM t_names nm
  INNER JOIN t_gender tg ON tg.rowid = nm.rowid
  INNER JOIN  t_salary sl ON sl.rowid = nm.rowid
```

what i given you is a suggestion for your scenario. But if this is a real world scenario, better to discuss this with your team and bring up a good structure for the table with Primary key, sequence number for the table.

at least add a new column as and set it as a identity column, and then it will create a sequence for your table.

[image]

if you created a sequence number as i explained you, then there is a 99% possibility to retrieve your exact result set

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_names
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY seq) rowid, NAME FROM Heading 
WHERE NAME IS NOT NULL;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_gender
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY seq) rowid, gender FROM Heading 
WHERE gender IS NOT NULL;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_salary
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY seq) rowid, salary FROM Heading 
WHERE salary IS NOT NULL;

SELECT nm.name, tg.gender, sl.salary FROM t_names nm
  INNER JOIN t_gender tg ON tg.rowid = nm.rowid
  INNER JOIN  t_salary sl ON sl.rowid = nm.rowid
```

[image]

Comment: *`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NAME) rowid, gender FROM Heading WHERE gender IS NOT NULL;`* means ORDER BY NULL on shown source data which is obviously non-deterministic.

Comment: *`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY seq) rowid, gender FROM Heading ..`* will produce "unknown column 'seq'" error.

Comment: The column adding won't help in concurrent environ, the rows inserted by parallel insertions may mix. And `ORDER BY seq` will produce incorrect output.

Comment: @Akina kindly requesting from you to cancel the given -1 value again.

Comment: @Akina that's why i told you to read my document first. i clearly explain it at my first paragraph also.

Comment: @akina what we are doing in here is helping to others as a support. read the whole section first and give your feedback. We spend our impotent time for them. Some people not giving any help, but make others disappointments.

Comment: I am convinced that OP task in its current state is absolutely unsolvable. Read the question in my comment to OP - it is critical for correct answering and even for the task solvability.

Comment: @akina that's clear and noted. But sometime we are getting this kind of stupid situations in our real world scenarios. in that case, we are also getting stuck and help less. For that giving them a small help is gold while they staying clueless